# how to manage simultaneous DOM modification

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flux

I am new to react and flux. I have a web application which I need to develop using react and flux partially. However, there is an other third party engine which gets connected with application and manipulates the DOM of the web page using plain javascript without react.

So, as the react based component creation deals with virtual dom concept, there are problems with simultaneous DOM modification. Can anyone please suggest me how to manage dom modifications by both React and third party engine at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the React Component lifecycle method [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) to decide who should be responsible for rendering the DOM.

For example, if you want to let the third part engine to completely take over the rendering of your React `component` after the initial rendering, you can implement the `shouldComponentUpdate()` to explicitly return `false`.

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So, if I return false, then when ever any action happens, Instead of React  creating virtual dom, making changes and rerendering the dom, third party engine should take care of DOM manipulations is it? If so, we will lose the point of using React (virtual dom manipulation). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This generally is the problem with using multiple frameworks/tools to render DOM, the division of responsibility can be very complex depending on what third party engine you're using, it can be messy to coordinating both renderers working together on the same component. Also, you don't lose the point of using React since you only delegate the rendering of **a single react component** to the third party engine, rest of the react components will still leverage benefits of virtual DOM.

Comment: Therefore I recommend you decide on **either or**, instead of using **both**. It's not worth the effort to dig into binding third party engine DOM manipulations with React (sounds like a hefty new layer you need to create yourself) **UNTIL** you benchmark and clearly identify there is a performance issue.